# PHP using phpseclib - exec(ls...) command doesn't find a file that was just created and exists on the disk

Tags: php, linux, exec, phpseclib

Using phpseclib from my PHP application, I am running a perl .pl script which creates a file on the remote server's drive/folder in one of the exec() commands.  This works fine and the file exists.  The next exec() does an 'ls' command to retrieve the full filename which contains a date/time stamp on the end of the file name that is unknown.  When it runs, it doesn't find the file when it is there and I can see it when doing a manual 'ls' on the Linux system.  I believe it might be a timing issue, so I also included a sleep 15 in between creation and doing the 'ls' command, but this did not resolve the issue.  And if I run the program again, creating a 2nd file, then the 'ls' returns the filename for the first file I generated.  I didn't see an fclose in the documentation, but did see it in some other posts here that might lead me to believe this might also be the issue.  Has anyone else experienced this issue and how did you resolve?  Thanks.

Updated:  Code snippet added....

```
            $ssh2->login(LINUX_USER,LINUX_PASS);
            $connected = $ssh2->isAuthenticated();
            if ($connected) {
                //$_SESSION['feedback'] .= "Connection and authentication successful to " . LINUX_SVR . ".<br>";
                $cmd_string = "/usr/bin/perl-report.pl " . LINUX_ENV . " " . $parm1 . " " . $parm2;
                $error = $ssh2->exec($cmd_string);
                if ($error) {
                    $_SESSION['feedback'] .= "Unable to execute command to create the Report - contact Operations with this error.<br>";
                    $_SESSION['feedback'] .= $ssh2->getLog();
                } else {
                    $_SESSION['feedback'] .= "Report successfully created for ID " . $parm2 . ".<br>";
                    //get the full name of the file created
                    $cmd_string = "sleep 15";
                    $ssh2->exec($cmd_string);
                    $cmd_string = "ls /root/Report-" . $parm1 . "-" . $parm2 . "-" . $date . "*";
                    $error = $ssh2->exec($cmd_string);
                    if (empty($error)) {
                        $_SESSION['feedback'] .= "Unable to execute command to obtain report name - contact Operations with this error.<br>";
                        $_SESSION['feedback'] .= $ssh2->getLog();
                    } else {
                        $filename = $ssh2->exec($cmd_string);
                        $filename = substr($filename, 6, strlen($filename));
                        $_SESSION['feedback'].= "The file name created is " . $filename . "<br>";
                        //verify that the filename is valid
                        if (substr($filename,0,7)=="Report-") {
                            //mail the attachment to the emailaddr
                            $cmd_string = "echo 'Requested Report attached.' | mail -s '" . $filename . "' -a '/root/" . $filename . "' " . $emailaddr . "\n";
                            $error = $ssh2->exec($cmd_string);
                            if ($error) {
                                $_SESSION['feedback'] .= "Unable to successfully email the requested report - contact Operations with this error.<br>";
                                $_SESSION['feedback'] .= $ssh2->getLog();
                            } else {
                                $_SESSION['feedback'] .= "Report successfully emailed to " . $emailaddr . ".  Process complete.<br>";
                                $_SESSION['feedback'] .= $ssh2->getLog();
                            }
                        } else {
                            $_SESSION['feedback'] .= "Unable to email attachment as filename is invalid - contact Operations with this error.<br>";
                            $_SESSION['feedback'] .= $ssh2->getLog();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $_SESSION['feedback'] .= "Connection and authentication failed to " . LINUX_SVR . ".<br>";
            }
            //disconnect when done
            $ssh2->reset();
            $ssh2->disconnect();
        }
```

Comment: It's hard to comment without seeing actual code but I do have to wonder if the issue isn't caused by you trying to run multiple `exec()`'s. `exec()` does not behave as most people expect it would. http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#chdir elaborates.

Comment: Yes, I've tried issuing multiple commands to the exec() and it works for the cd, pwd, and ls commands, but when I try to call the .pl script, then it won't run for some reason and doesn't really give me any log errors.  It's almost like it is being ignored.  I'm also having a second problem with my mailx call for some reason, but that is a separate issue.  I will see if I can post part of the code....I can't post all of it because it has some proprietary information.

Comment: At the top of the code I also have this...set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . './includes/phpseclib');
include('Net/SSH2.php');
include('Math/BigInteger.php');
include('Crypt/Random.php');
include('Crypt/Hash.php');
include('Crypt/Base.php');
define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', NET_SSH2_LOG_COMPLEX);

Comment: The `sleep 15` shouldn't be necessary. I do note that that when you do `$cmd_string = "ls /root/Report-" . $parm1 . "-" . $parm2 . "-" . $date . "*";` that `$date` isn't defined anywhere nor is it used anywhere else. On top of that you're basically running the same command twice. You do `$error = $ssh2->exec($cmd_string);` and then `$filename = $ssh2->exec($cmd_string);`

Comment: Also, while you're at it, you might as well post `/usr/bin/perl-report.pl` because that could be relevant as well.